# In AngularFire, why is the auth.user property null in the controller, but not the view?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

There is a user logged into Firebase, and in my views, $scope.auth returns the current logged in user and I can access its data.

In my controller however, $scope.auth.user returns null.

```
myApp.controller('quoteController', ['$scope', '$firebase', '$firebaseSimpleLogin',
  function($scope, $firebase, $firebaseSimpleLogin) {

    $scope.auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(dataRef);

    console.log($scope.auth.user);
  });
```

console.log($scope.auth.user) == 'null'.

Why is this the case? I know that the user is logged in. The angularFire docs says that, "the login state for Simple Login is global to your application, even if multiple $firebaseSimpleLogin objects are created." So shouldn't $scope.auth.user contain the current user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Login requires contacting the server asynchronously. You can't immediately access the variable on the next line because it hasn't been retrieved yet. Additionally, you'll need to call login() before a user object will exist. Assuming there is a login persisted from another page view, or login() has been called, you can take a few approaches to accomplish what you want.

Use [$getCurrentUser()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#getcurrentuser) to wait for the auth process to resolve and fetch the user account that is currently authenticated:

```
angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"])
  .controller("SampleController", ["$scope", "$firebase", "$firebaseSimpleLogin",
    function($scope, $firebase, $firebaseSimpleLogin) {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/");
      $scope.auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);
      $scope.auth.$getCurrentUser().then(function(user) {
         console.log(user);
      });
    }
  ]);
```

Utilize the [auth events](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#events):

```
angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"])
  .controller("SampleController", ["$scope", "$firebase", "$firebaseSimpleLogin",
    function($scope, $firebase, $firebaseSimpleLogin) {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/");
      $scope.auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);
      $scope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:login', function() {
         console.log($scope.auth.user);
      });
    }
  ]);
```

Or you can use the promise returned when [login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#login-provider-options) is called:

```
angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"])
  .controller("SampleController", ["$scope", "$firebase", "$firebaseSimpleLogin",
    function($scope, $firebase, $firebaseSimpleLogin) {
      var ref = new Firebase("https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/");
      $scope.auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);

      $scope.auth.$login('twitter').then(function() {
          console.log($scope.auth.user);
      });
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: @Kato.  So if you want to use something like `user.uid` within a random controller, `user.uid` needs to be introduced using one of these methods?  It seems like the variable already exists in the app and was just curious if there's another way to access it within my different controllers.

Comment: @KylePennell check out angularFire-seed, which stores it [as a service](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/js/simpleLogin.js#L14), so all any controller need do is call simpleLogin.user or simpleLogin.getUser(). And even better, you can use `resolve` and [inject it as a dependency](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-angular-authentication).

Answer (score 2):

This most probably is due to async nature of call to `firebaseSimpleLogin`. Even their example has a callback

```
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(chatRef, function(error, user) {
  if (error) {
    // an error occurred while attempting login
    console.log(error);
  } else if (user) {
    // user authenticated with Firebase
    console.log('User ID: ' + user.uid + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
  } else {
    // user is logged out
  }
});
```

If you check the value in a callback you should see the user data.

Comment: All correct, however, $firebaseSimpleLogin is part of the angularFire lib and works just slightly differently (using either events broadcast on $rootScope or by using promises on the login/logout methods)

Comment: OK, I don't have experience with angulrfire library, this was based on the samples :)